# Moving stack elements back to a Single linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to move list elements to the stack and back to the list again, reversing their order.

I'm having trouble with the last bit of transferring the stack back into the list.
I've been using the `stack.pop();` in different ways but nothing seems to work.

I'm able to just print out the output of `stack.pop` so far, but I really want to be able to transfer the stack contents back into the list.

```
    public class ReverseArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EmptyStackException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MyLinkedList<GameEntry>myList = new MyLinkedList<>();

        //populate the list
        myList.addFirst(new Node<GameEntry>(new GameEntry("Marche", 313), null));
        myList.addFirst(new Node<GameEntry>(new GameEntry("Apricot", 754), null));
        myList.addFirst(new Node<GameEntry>(new GameEntry("Dragon", 284), null));
        myList.addFirst(new Node<GameEntry>(new GameEntry("Erasure", 653), null));

        //print the list
        System.out.println(myList);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("New Reversed List:");
        //reverse the list elements 
        reverse(myList);



    }

    public static <V> void reverse ( MyLinkedList<V> list) throws EmptyStackException{
        //code to reverse goes here
        NodeStack<GameEntry> stack = new NodeStack<GameEntry>();
        Node<GameEntry> scores = list.getHead();

        for ( int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++){
            stack.push(scores.getElement());
            scores = scores.getNext();

        }

        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");

        }

    }// end reverse
}//end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep order from the stack, so add them at the end of a new `LinkedList`:

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
    GameEntry entry = stack.pop();
    list.addLast(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the list to only contain the reversed elements you have to clear the list at first. Depending on your implementation you have a `clear()` method or must call `remove()` several times until the list is empy.

Afterwards you can add code like this:

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
    GameEntry entry = stack.pop();
    list.addFirst(entry);
}
```

That way you should have the reversed order of your elements in the list.

An alternativ would be implementing the `List` Interface with your MyLinkedList and use the `Collections.reverse()`.

---

Totally missed that the order would be the same as on the input list. Therefore you have two options:

1. Use a Queue instead of a Stack.
2. Use second Stack that gets filled with the contents of your first Stack. This may look like:

   ```
   NodeStack<GameEntry> secondStack = new NodeStack<GameEntry>(); 
   while(!stack.isEmpty()){
       secondStack.push(stack.pop());
   }

   while(!secondStack.isEmpty()){
       GameEntry entry = secondStack.pop();
       list.addFirst(entry);
   }
   ```

Comment: Elements should be added from the back of list to keep reverse order.